# Python Dash-uploader upload multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

My code consists in the following:

```
import dash_uploader as du
import os
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

directory = r'C:\Users'
def uploaded_files():
    files = []
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        file = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        files.append({'label': file, 'value': file})
    return files

app.layout = html.Div([
  du.Upload(
    id='dash-uploader',
    filetypes=['csv', 'xls', 'xlsx'],
    max_files=2,
  ),

  html.Div(id='callback-output', style={'display': 'none'})

  dbc.Select(
    id="browse_content",
    placeholder="Select Data File",
    options=[],
  ),
])

@du.callback(
    output=Output('callback-output', 'children'),
    id='dash-uploader'
)
def update_list(filenames):
    print('update_list', filenames)
    return filenames

@app.callback(
    [Output('browse_content', 'options')],
    [Input('callback-output', 'children')]
)
def get_a_list(files):
    filenames = uploaded_files()
    print('get_a_list', files, filenames)
    return filenames
```

But when uploading 2 files: file1.xlsx and file2.xlsx, I get the following print:

> update_list ['C:\Users\file1.xlsx']
> get_a_list ['C:\Users\file1.xlsx'] [{'label': 'file1.xlsx', 'value': 'file1.xlsx'}]

Both files have been uploaded in the folder, but it seems that callbacks stop after the first file being uploaded: even the line filenames = uploaded_files() in the callback "get_a_list" returns only the first file...

Any idea what's wrong here please?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the same issue as [\[bug\] isCompleted callback is only executed on first file](https://github.com/np-8/dash-uploader/issues/5), which has not been yet fixed. Currently (v.0.5.0) dash-uploader can upload multiple files, but there will be only one callback call, unfortunately. The quick and dirty workaround would be to use .zip files, but with two files that is probably too much work.

Comment: This is now fixed in dash-uploader 0.7.0. The pre-release if available in pip with `python -m pip install dash-uploader --pre`.